# element toolkitscriptmanager is not a known element

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been working on a website for a while now in asp.net and c# on Visual Studio 2008. I'm using AjaxControlToolkit and I have used a number of controls successfully for quite a while. I usually work on a temporary file and after making changes and seeing that they work in the developer server I copy them to the IIS server. I've never had any problems with this. Today I did this also and after copying to the IIS the ajax toolkit exender controls are not working. In the site file on the IIS the toolkitscriptmanager is underlined in green and I'm recieving the following message: element toolkitscriptmanager is not a known element as a tooltip message. This is happening also with all other ajax toolkit controls on the page. Afterwords this spred to other pages on the site also. 
I have the following line on all the pages with the problem:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>.
```

I also added a similar line in the masterPage and have the following line in the webconfig page of the site:

```
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />.
```

This is the full warning message on the error list: "Element 'ToolkitScriptManager' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing." The compiler gives no compilation errors and the web.cinfig file is not missing. What is the problem and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Check the version is correct, clean the solution, if this doesn't work try removing the assebly reference "<5@ Register" and then dragging a fresh control onto the design or code surface.

Comment: @Lloyd how do I check that the version is correct? Also why would an identical copy work on the developper server and not on the IIS server

Comment: Are the DEv and PROD servers setup with the same version of the .Net Framework, is this the same as the solutions? Click on the AjaxControlToolkit in the references pane and see what version you are using it should match the Application Target Framework and AjaxControlToolkit version.